# Cloud Firestore with Angularfire 2 - Quota Error for retrieving large data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Whenever I try to retrieve large data from Firestore in my angular application, I get below error.

***@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.5.9): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)***

What can be done in this case? Once this error comes, Chrome browser tab also hangs. I have no option than to kill the browser. Moreover, if the same code is written in Python and run from PyCharm Community Edition, no such error is received.

However I need the data to be retrieved in my angular application. What can be done in this case?

Comment: Try splitting it in to a smaller chunks. Can't help you more without any information about your document structure.